# Suggestion On Objectify Entities Creation From Base Entity Class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Sorry For improper question title, i dint get any relevant title for my question.

I started using Objectify-Appengine in a new project, 
I Would like to hear what would be the better solution to create entities from base entity class, consider base class as,

```
@Entity
public Class User { ... some properties...}
```

then i would like to create some other entities like as below,

```
@EntitySubclass
public class AdminUser extends User {}

@EntitySubclass
public class Staff extends User {}
```

and important point is, **i dont want to persist Base Entity "User", meaning there will not be any person of this type.**

is my current solution is good? or is there any better way of doing this?

Any Help or suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no objectify expert here, but it seems wrong to me that you have '@Entity public Class User...' if you aren't going to have an entity of type User.

My impression is that you just want to have 2 entity types (Staff and Admin), and you want some shared Java code in a common base class.  So you don't need to use @EntitySubclass at all.  So how about:

```
public Class User { ... some properties...}

@Entity
public class AdminUser extends User {}

@Entity
public class Staff extends User {}
```

Comment: Ya i should have done that, the reason why i set @Entity for user is,  each of admin or staff entity can have user being its parent, which will be helpful for polymorphic query with objectify , like get all users list, etc.